# How can I prevent URLs in an `eprint` field from overflowing in the references in the CEURART latex template?

Tags: bibliographies, templates

Workshops whose proceedings are published on the [CEUR Workshop Proceedings](http://ceur-ws.org/) website demand authors to use the [CEURART latex template](https://ceurws.wordpress.com/2020/03/31/ceurws-publishes-ceurart-paper-style/).

If I add a reference with a long URL such as

```
@article{cts12980,
author = {Yamaguchi, Shingo and Kaneko, Masayuki and Narukawa, Mamoru},
title = {Approval success rates of drug candidates based on target, action, modality, application, and their combinations},
journal = {Clinical and Translational Science},
volume = {14},
number = {3},
pages = {1113-1122},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1111/cts.12980},
url = {https://ascpt.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/cts.12980},
eprint = {https://ascpt.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/cts.12980},
year = {2021}
}
```

the URL overflows:

[image]

([Latex sources](https://www.overleaf.com/read/cktfnkjjbcgg) where I took the screenshot from.)

How can I prevent that?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the `eprint` field for a URL? I think the `eprint` field is not meant hold an entire URL but rather an identifier. Also your `doi` field should be `doi = {10.1111/cts.12980}`, to ensure the corresponding hyperlink will be correct.

Comment: @luki thanks, good point, I simply used the bib entry provided by the website where I found the article. Your comment answered the question! You're welcome to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [luki](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/109339/luki) mentioned in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636114/how-can-i-prevent-urls-in-an-eprint-field-from-overflowing-in-the-references-i#comment1585351_636114), `eprint` field is not meant hold an entire URL but rather an identifier.

The `url` field also suffers from overflows. To fix it, add the following:

Right before `\begin{document}`:

```
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}
```

Right before `\bibliography{sample-ceur}`:

```
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu\relax
```

Example:

[image]

becomes

[image]